# Why are named functions treated differently than arrow functions in circular dependencies?

Tags: typescript, lambda, types, circular-dependency

I'm trying to roll my own dependency injection mechanism in TypeScript, and I've come across an interesting problem. When declaring my dependencies, I have to use named functions instead of arrow functions (which are my default typically), otherwise I get circular declaration errors.

Below are the set of types that make up my dependency resolver:

```
type CollectionTemplate = {
    [key: string]: (...args: any) => any
}

type RegistryTemplate = {
    [key: string]: CollectionTemplate
}

type RegistryCollection<R extends RegistryTemplate> = keyof R

type CollectionEntry<C extends CollectionTemplate> = keyof C

type BaseRegistry<R extends RegistryTemplate> = R

type BaseContext<R extends RegistryTemplate> = {
    [C in RegistryCollection<R>]: {
        [E in CollectionEntry<R[C]>]: ReturnType<R[C][E]>
    }
}

type BaseUseDep<R extends RegistryTemplate> =
    <C extends RegistryCollection<R>, E extends CollectionEntry<R[C]>>
        (collection: C, entry: E) => BaseContext<R>[C][E]
```

Now, this all works fine when I use named functions:

```
type DepRegistry = BaseRegistry<typeof registry>
type DepContext = BaseContext<DepRegistry>
type UseDep = BaseUseDep<DepRegistry>

function greet(deps: UseDep)
{
    return (name: string) =>
    {
        const console = deps('system', 'console')
        console.log(name)
    }
}

function printGreeting(deps: UseDep)
{
    return () =>
    {
        const greet = deps('social', 'greet')
        greet('John')
    }
}

const registry = {
    system: {
        console: () => console,
    },
    social: {
        greet,
        printGreeting,
    }
}
```

However, if I declare these functions with arrow functions instead of named functions, I get the following errors:

```
Type alias 'DepRegistry' circularly references itself. ts(2456)
Type alias 'UseDep' circularly references itself. ts(2456)
```

Why is this? Is it simply because I'm assigning a function to a variable instead of declaring an explicit function?

EDIT: Here are playgrounds with [named functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwRAxsAlnAdgFQgWzAQENhoBeKAbwCgp6oBtAawhAC4oBnYAJ3SwBzALqcAFADopxXoK6diWEAEoo5AHxRFIGgF8aNUJCgAlCIPQ9eIPIRJk11OgxZtOVgSM7wkqDNlsiUgg9AyNoMwsrEB9kNEwsAB4TKAgADzIsABMuU3NLPhsCILJNSlYQOAAzUzDwaFi-BIBRLELEmFSMiGzcxviA4vsIMqgK6tg64wAhYi4ISILrZK7MnLyowsDh0ZMp6Fn5+Db04BXTnvXF6O3g0doGJk6BDaWYxDj-JJN1USdHx6MZpQF79L6tdomRgwYS-ThmYAAV14uHqyWhwiBsOc9H0+kM9SghwgAFV5gARCBgc7dXqvG5DO5qHFQDqrS65a6FMEJZLqAA0UGBFzpPOwEOWUJh6nULMeYhQHya2G8gp6hU4zVUGiJcwgxzIGT5GKx+yglLAXOsjmJVpAiXCE14+WisvC5qpBtONr1XqNFrtbsJZIgFp98xDFsSAZdhVlNCqiKwAywUEEzogwDEWSp8igkapyhoDwYzqRKKgYiwxHwEHcfE82tljxLAKgiqwPHb2C4iAoUBzYC4YgA5FwQDwCCPBSOO73kCOi236HO+xIEHBBFWaxAlww8QZE8mvlAwPw2gBxDMYITZ3OcAtgIutqBl5GpsRNlkvx5z4Bp69HEHYcxzgFB0GIBBpygEd0wgTNFzlBg4MzUcACk4AACywRDHgPGg-1fWNrUoF9x0nfBOB-BhV2QcQm27Ts+35FldBYx5e3AyCqKQ+gUOAdjlzPARgCveCb0EQTcT0IA) and with [arrow functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwRAxsAlnAdgFQgWzAQENhoBeKAbwCgp6oBtAawhAC4oBnYAJ3SwBzALqcAFADopxXoK6diWEAEoo5AHxRFIGgF8aNUJCgAlCIPQ9eIPIRJk11OgxZtOVgSM7wkqDNlsiUgg9AyNoMwsrEB9kNEwsAB4TKAgADzIsABMuU3NLPhsCILJNSlYQOAAzUzDwaFi-BIBRLELEmFSMiGzcxviA4vsIMqgK6tg64wAhYi4ISILrZK7MnLyowsDh0ZMp6Fn5+Db04BXTnvXF6O3g0doGJk6BDaWYxDj-JJN1USdHx6MZpQF79L6tdomRgwYS-ThmYAAV14uHqyWhwiBsOc9H0+kM9SghwgAFV5gARCBgc7dXqvG5DO5qHFQDqrS65a6FMEJZLqAA0UGBFzpPOwEOWUJh6nULMeYhQHya2G8gp6hU4zVUGiJcwgxzIGT5GKx+yglLAXOsjmJVpAiXCE14+WisvC5qpBtONr1XqNFrtbsJZIgFp98xDFsSAZdhVlNEVWB4UEEzogwEcYiyVPkUEjVO1mjEWGI+Ag7j4nkLNAeDETyfriAoUGzYC4YgA5FwQDwCB3BR3G8gO8oWUOIBIEHBBMXSxBR-j6xmwPw2gBxNMYISZ1u5-NgQtQMTV2v0JcpzeOXedrhwFDoYgIftQDupiDpkcst-pzsAKTgAAWWCfou2DJs6mzWpQp7cD2ZD4JwMGPOO4iHuO-IsroGGPLe96PohcoMN+wDYQC9ArgIwAbu+W6CKRuJ6EAA).

Comment: You've given some great background, but can you show the exact code causing problems? Bonus points for a working code example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). I think we need to be clear about what "declare these functions with arrow functions instead of named functions" actually means.

Comment: @spender I've updated the question with links to both working and broken playgrounds!

Comment: As a sidenote. If you annotate your arrow functions everything works ok. https://tsplay.dev/m3A02w. I believe it's the same problem as describe here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43047 . But will wait for someone who can explain it thoroughly.

Comment: Now _that_ is interesting... I'm going to play around with this a bit and see if I can get something usable out of this.

Comment: It seems to me your question essentially boils down [to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68167383/how-to-avoid-circular-dependencies-when-using-function-expressions-in-typescript). It'd be possible to prepopulate the type declarations (either as in @aleksxor code, or in mine); can't help wondering is that the only way though.

Comment: And yes, at least for now using [type annotations](https://tsplay.dev/mA7lQw) seems to be the path of least resistance, if one insists on using function expressions.

Comment: Yeah, so far it seems that explicitly setting the type of the variable holding the function is the only way to use arrow functions in circular declarations. Would love to find some way to do that in a different way

Comment: I believe you should raise the issue in ts repo.
It seems to be some inconsistency between arrow functions and fn expression.
See this issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*following answer partially explains the issue; it meant to be a comment*

I think, the reason behind the discrepancy between named and arrow functions *might be* the `lazy vs eager` resolution of type signatures.

[Anders Hejlsberg compared `interface vs type` resolution in this GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540):

> The trick is to make the recursive back references within interface types. This works because resolution of interface base types and interface members is deferred, whereas resolution of type aliases is performed eagerly.

A signature of a `function` can be specified with  `interface { (...params: Params): Return }` and therefore the lazy resolution strategy is used by Typescript compiler and recursive definitions are allowed.

I do not know why arrow functions are treated differently but it *seems* their type signature is evaluated eagerly.

---

I often follow a similar pattern of dependencies register / injection and encountered the issue before. Never thought of replacing arrows with regular functions though. Good to know it is a possibility. You could as well consider avoiding circular dependencies in the first place.

The issue itself is highly-counterintuitive and very interesting at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I mostly agree with you on the eager vs. lazy resolution, though if that's the case it confuses me why explicitly declaring the type of the arrow function seems to let this work. Perhaps it's also able to be lazily resolved?

Either way, I'm considering moving away from this towards a single imported dependency resolver that I can just mock using my testing framework. It'll be a bit messier, but I think it should work for more use-cases than a curried dependency resolver. We shall see.